# Flutter web - ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in release

Tags: flutter, web, dart

Flutter web release is not working, it works fine for `flutter run -d chrome` but when I try to `flutter run --release` or `flutter build web`, then there are some errors.

I have tried different channels and `flutter clean`

[image]

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64511356/11675817). You can run those commands.

Comment: its not working.

Comment: How are you running the site after you build it?

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and navigate to the "your_app\build\web" and run the follow command:

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

After that open your browse at localhost:8000

You can find more details in here (https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/web) see "Building the app for release" session