# Flutter build web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-release

I'm new in flutter and I want to build web application by flutter web,`flutter build apk` is worked for me, but when I run `Flutter build web`
[I have this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zExwr.png)

I followed up every step  according to [this document](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety) and use `// @dart=2.9` top of all of my class that has error null check.

do you have any idea about this problem?!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62316589/flutter-build-web-is-throwing-the-error-missing-index-html

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/64511356/11675817

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use these command--->

```
flutter channel beta
flutter config --enable-web
flutter create .
```

After creating you will find a web folder in your project

**restart IDE or Editor if needed.
Note:  You must have google chrome**

```
flutter devices
```

there you will be found your chrome
then simply run or use the command ->

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the channel master for flutter in order to build web version, more details [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/web).

In resume, do:

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-web
```

After that, just run `flutter build web` and then, go in `root_of_your_app/build/web` and run a web server inside like python with `python -m http.server 8000` and go to http://localhost:8000 to see your app on any browsers.